# How to write a specific line of a text file?

Tags: c#, forms, file, text

How to write a specific line of a text file in C# FORMS?

For example I have a txt file at D:\Desktop\asd.txt, I don't know the text file's content.

I want to change the text of the 5th line to Winter,
and after that e.g. the 3rd line to Summer.

How can I do that with the easiest way? Can anyone write me a concrete code?

Comment: Read the whole file into memory, in a data structure that supports the changes you want to make, make the changes, write the whole file back. Look at `File.ReadAllFiles` to start with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\Desktop\asd.txt");
lines[5] = "some value";
File.WriteAllLines(@"D:\Desktop\asd.txt", lines);
```

Comment: Index Out Of Range Exception. What can I do?

Comment: What's the content of `D:\Desktop\asd.txt`?

Comment: "I don't know the text file's content"..  I know, but it can change..

Comment: If you want to change line 5, you first need to ensure there are 5 lines in the file, you can put the contents of the file into a list instead of an array, and add empty lines until you got enough.

Comment: I just want to change the 5th or the 3rd line (e.g.). There are 5 lines, I don't have to create them.